# Can Dagger2 injecte Retrofit2 to remote service?

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, remote-server

How to use Dagger2/Retrofit2 injection remote service?

Is not a remote service, it can be injected into the success. Whether it is because the remote service is in a new app. So in the new App user retrofit error.

So how to inject remote services in the new APP? If you can inject, then the injection of the class is not the same as the original APP is not the same?

Does Dagger2 not support remote service dependency injection? But still need to operate services through AIDL.I use Dagger2 dependency injection retrofit2 to the repository.Error when calling the network interface.

Thx!

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

**But I not uer SharedPreferences in this.Just useing retrofit calling the network interface.**

**AndroidManifest:**

```xml
<service
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="false"
  android:name=".Service"
  android:process=":remote.service">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.ExampleService"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**Service:**

```java
 @Inject
  public Recorder(Application context, DataRepo dataRepo) {
    mDataRepo = dataRepo;
  }

//...

Recorder tryRecordering(Context context) {
    KLog.i(RECORDER, this);
    mSubscriptions.add(Observable.zip(mDataRepo.getList(),
        mDataRepo.fetchHasAuth(), mDataRepo.fetchSetting(),//Error on this
        new Func3<List<Data>, Boolean, SettingResponse, List<Data>>() {
          @Override
          public List<Data> call(List<Data> dataList, Boolean aBoolean,SettingResponse SettingResponse) {
            //do something
            return dataList;
          }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Action1<List<Data>>() {
          @Override
          public void call(List<Data> data) {
           //do something
          }
        }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
          @Override
          public void call(Throwable throwable) {
            KLog.e(RECORDER,throwable);
            if (hasAuth) {
              //do something
            }
          }
        }));
    return this;
  }
```

Comment: Did you include the service injector in your Application? Could you include your `Application` code please?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Thanks for the reply, I just found out where the problem is. When my team people injected in the Application, to determine whether the main process. Although I do not know why this judgment, but remove the judgment to solve the problem. Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Does Dagger2 not support remote service dependency injection?I use Dagger2 dependency injection retrofit to the repository.Error when calling the network interface.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference